Setup project broken after update to VS2022 17.10
Over a year ago I started building a tool for internal use and distribute it through an MSI and setup.exe (the setup.exe is necessary to check if the current version is already installed or if an upgrade has to be done, this is automatically provided by the Setup project that comes with Visual Studio 2022). This worked fine until June 2024 on Windows 10.
Then, 4 to 5 weeks ago, I updated Visual Studio 2022 to version 17.10 and went on vacation (that's on me). When I came back, I was still able to build my project's application but I was unable to get my setup project to run and build a proper setup.msi and setup.exe.
Running the project outputs only an unrecoverable issue: 0x80004002. Further investigation revealed nothing useful, sadly.
I then turned to build the setup differently and started a new WiX project (which for some reason is v3.x in Visual Studio 2022, compared to v5 for dotnet). While building my first package I get an error telling me that 32bit components cannot be packed into a 64bit package. This got me thinking that maybe the issue comes from dependencies somehow being installed differently. I was unable to find out how and where this happened, nonetheless I'm able to build an MSI with a 64bit executable (my application as exe) and dll and package it into a 32bit installer package.
I really don't get what happened nor have I any clue how to get the original Setup project to run again.
After updating my machine to Windows 11 today, I got a new error (which I'll try to fix by repairing the Visual Studio 2022 installation):
Ergebnis: Import "Microsoft.Publish.Framework.VisualStudio.PublishPackage._publishService (ContractName="Microsoft.Publish.Framework.VisualStudio.IPublishService")" kann nicht für Teil "Microsoft.Publish.Framework.VisualStudio.PublishPackage" festgelegt werden.
Element: Microsoft.Publish.Framework.VisualStudio.PublishPackage._publishService (ContractName="Microsoft.Publish.Framework.VisualStudio.IPublishService") -->  Microsoft.Publish.Framework.VisualStudio.PublishPackage

Has anyone experienced similar problems with Setup projects suddenly not working anymore?

Here are some steps to help you troubleshoot and potentially resolve the problem:
1. Repair Visual Studio Installation
Since you've already updated to Windows 11, start by repairing your Visual Studio installation:
Open Visual Studio Installer.
Select your Visual Studio installation.
Click on "Repair."
2. Check for Updates
Make sure you have the latest updates for Visual Studio:
Open Visual Studio Installer.
Check for any pending updates for both Visual Studio and any installed components.
3. Review Project Configuration
Open your setup project and check the configuration settings.
Ensure that the target platform (x86/x64) matches your application and dependencies.
4. Check Dependencies
Verify the dependencies of your application. Make sure they are compatible with the version of Visual Studio you are using.
Check if any components or SDKs need to be reinstalled or updated.
5. Rebuild the Solution
Clean and rebuild your entire solution. Sometimes intermediate files can cause issues:
Right-click on the solution in Solution Explorer and select Clean Solution.
Then select Rebuild Solution.
6. Use WiX for Setup Project
If the built-in Setup project continues to fail, consider fully migrating to WiX. Here are some tips:
Ensure you are using the correct version of WiX (v3.x) and that your project settings align with it.
Create a new WiX installer project and make sure to define the architecture (x86/x64) properly.
7. Check Build Output
Examine the detailed build output for any specific errors or warnings:
Go to View > Output.
Set the dropdown to "Build" to get more context about what might be failing.
8. Look for Community Solutions
Sometimes other developers face similar issues. Check forums or community posts specific to Visual Studio 2022 and setup projects.
9. Logs and Error Codes
The error code 0x80004002 indicates a "No such interface supported" error. Look for logs or any additional error details that might provide more context.
10. Fallback to Previous Version
If all else fails and the project was working before the update, consider reverting to an earlier version of Visual Studio (if feasible) until you can isolate the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy
